# Makefile to build and debug a C++ console app

Tags: c++, makefile, make

I had to create this makefile to build and debug a C++ console app. I just need some hints and tips on how I can organize my makefile.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=helloWorld.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=helloWorld

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

debug: CXXFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g
debug: CCFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g
debug: helloWorld

clean:
    rm *o helloWorld

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **Making sources?**

  The line

  ```
  all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
  ```

  asks `make` to build `$(SOURCES)`, in this case `helloWorld.cpp`. Is it possible to build it? Strictly speaking there are situations when you do want to build the source file (e.g. fetch it from `git/cvs/sccs`) but it is not applicable here: no rule is provided. Generally you don't want to build something which doesn't depend on anything. In any case, let `make` deduce; this is what it is good for.

  ```
  all: $(EXECUTABLE)
  ```

  is what you want.
- **Be consistent**

  `all` depends on `$(EXECUTABLE)`, but `debug` depends on `helloWorld`. Once you defined a macro, use it everywhere.
- **Synonymous targets**

  Consider the scenario: `make`; `./helloWold`; something goes wrong and you want to debug; `make debug`: everything is up to date. To have a debug build you must intervene with `make clean`. A good practice is to separate debug and release builds into different directories.
- **Automatic dependencies**

  In your example the `.o` file depends only on a corresponding `.cpp`. In real life the `.cpp` has some `#include`s - and the `.o` must depend on them all. Otherwise you will end up with an inconsistent build. Listing the `.h` dependencies manually is tedious and error prone. The standard practice is to let the compiler generate them automatically. For example, `g++` has `-MM`, `-MT`, etc options just for this purpose:

  ```
  DEPS := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)
  .cpp.d:
      $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM -MT -o $@ $<
  -include $(DEPS)
  ```
- **-c doesn't belong to CFLAGS**

  `-c` is typically not listed in a `CFLAGS`: you may want to generate various outputs (e.g. preprocessed source, assembly source, dependencies, documentation, etc) with the same set of flags. The way to achieve this is to specify `-c` or `-MM` or `-S` or whatever separately from other flags, e.g.

  ```
  .cpp.o:
      $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) ....

  .cpp.s:
      $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) ....
  ```

  etc.
- **CC**

  Traditionally a `c++` compiler is referred as `CXX` and uses `CXXFLAGS`. The `CC` and `CFLAGS` are reserved for plain `c`.

Comment: Your first point, that `all: $(SOURCES) asks make to build $(SOURCES)` is fundamentally wrong. It's saying that `all` *depends upon* `$(SOURCES)`. This is actually true, though it's basically pointless. You want to tell it that `all` depends on the executable, and make and then build the chain backward from the executable to the objects, and finally the source files. So your advice was right, but explanation...maybe not exactly wrong, but unclear at best.

Comment: @JerryCoffin unclear all right

Answer (score 2):

- **`CFLAGS`**

  The `CFLAGS` are C-specific and you always want to use `CXXFLAGS` for C++ code. You can expand the `CXXFLAGS` a bit so that you can write really compact code.

  I use this set of compiler options for both C and C++:

  ```
  -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Werror -fverbose-asm  -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion
  ```

  This answer is in the GCC manual so I won't explain what each option does. These options are present in any C or C++ project I start.
- **`.PHONY` target**

  It is a good idea to put the `all` and `debug` and `clean` to a `.PHONY` target as `make` can complain a bit about the file not being created.